# How to make netbeans trigger the System.in?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int num_strings = Integer.parseInt( br.readLine()), i;
```

This is just sample of my code, and I know the `System.in` will ask user to input and `br.readLine` will actually ask user input of oneline.
But the thing is when I run this, the output console just said:
run:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

never ask me the user input, it run through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need run the file not project, that shortkey is Shift + f6

Answer (score 1):

You build this. You should run it.
Click `Shift + F6` on main class.

For me, your code works well.
After pressing `Shift + F6` - console is waiting for input